# Why does this Fourier inner product equal this sum?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is part of a derivation in a text that I am struggling to follow. It says
that if we write $e_k(t) = e^{2 \pi i k t}$ then

$$\langle \sum_{n=- \infty}^{\infty} \langle f, e_n \rangle e_n,\sum_{m=- \infty}^{\infty} \langle f, e_m \rangle e_m \rangle = \sum_{n,m} \langle f, e_n\rangle \overline{\langle f, e_m\rangle} \langle e_n, e_m\rangle.$$

I don't see how this follows. Here $\langle., .\rangle$ is the L2 inner product, so $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt$.

Comment: You mean $e_n(t) = e^{2\pi i n t}$, right?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually holds for any inner product, simply by linearity.

Consider the following simpler case:

$$\langle \langle a,b\rangle c,\langle d,e\rangle f\rangle = \langle a,b\rangle\overline{\langle d,e\rangle} \langle c,f\rangle$$

Comment: Could you show why that holds?

Comment: It's true by definition for any inner product. Is the question to show that the particular integral you've defined is a proper inner product?

Comment: On also has to argue that you can take the limit out of the inner product. This is allowed due to the continuity of the inner product and Parseval's identity.

Comment: I see it now. I think you also have to use conjugate symmetry.